# Loopback Mysql Connector: BIT(1) is recognized always true

Tags: javascript, mysql, loopback

I am using Loopback 3.22 with loopback-connector-mysql 5.3.1.

When i configure loopback to covert `BIT(1)` mysql column as `boolean` it always returns `true`

```
"isActive": {
  "type": "Boolean",
  "required": false,
  "length": null,
  "precision": 1,
  "scale": null,
  "mysql": {
    "columnName": "is_active",
    "dataType": "bit",
    "dataLength": null,
    "dataPrecision": 1,
    "dataScale": null,
    "nullable": "Y"
  }
},
```

I have wasted so much time here, I even tried to use `before save` hooks, but column type validation kicks in before.

Making the column type `Binary` pushes the problem to the frontend.

Comment: for the record I patched `MySQL.prototype.fromColumnValue`, in order to get this thing working and move on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a know bug of LoopBack's MySQL connector, see the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/325

Answer (score 0):

for anyone stuck here, I dirty patched `MySQL.prototype.fromColumnValue`, in order to get this thing working ***until it gets fixed***

```
let MySQL = require("loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql").MySQL;

...
case 'Boolean':
        // extra case of Buffer(1)
        if (val instanceof Buffer && val.length === 1) {
          val = Boolean(val[0]);
        } else {
          // default case
          val = Boolean(val);
        }
...
```

Comment: I do not recomend to do this, and this is the reason why I did not mark my answer as accepted, but I have already a frontend ready using boolean values, and I have to solve the issue centrally instead of fixing  each model using a boolean property.